# Getting Values from JSON Array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, google-api

Here is my Request

```
$GoogleApiResult = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=11.0450,76.9200&destinations=11.0450,76.9455");
return $GoogleApiResult;
```

And my Response is

```
{ "destination_addresses" : [ "201, Koundampalayam, Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu 641030, India" ], "origin_addresses" : [ "1, Luna Plastics Road, Lakshmi Nagar, Coimbatore, Tamil Nadu 641025, India" ], "rows" : [ { "elements" : [ { "distance" : { "text" : "3.5 km", "value" : 3523 }, "duration" : { "text" : "6 mins", "value" : 382 }, "status" : "OK" } ] } ], "status" : "OK" }
```

How can i get the value of Distance (3.5km) and Duration (6 min) ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert json response to PHP array using json_decode function.

Use below code to get duration & distance from response from api:

```
$array=json_decode($json); //$json is api response
//var_dump($array);

echo $array->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->text;
echo $array->rows[0]->elements[0]->duration->text;
```